# Create locally discoverable service without mDNS

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, firefox-addon, p2p

I'm trying to create a service that runs on a Raspberry Pi. I'd like the service to broadcast itself in such a way that a Firefox add-on or web extension be able to find it. I've considered using mDNS, but that requires that users have an mDNS program installed and I am not sure that within the add-on I will have access to mDNS services. How should I proceed?

Note: The service only need be discoverable on the local LAN.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful here. Do you need your service to be discoverable on just the local LAN or over the entire Internet etc?

Comment: Just the local LAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic options in home networks are:

- mDNS
- LLMNR
- a router which supports inserting the locally DHCP-advertised hostnames into its local DNS zone
- hand-rolled multicast

Since browser extension APIs do not expose native sockets you have to hope that one of those solutions is already available or provide instructions to your users how to configure them.

Mozilla was working on an mDNS based browser solution called FlyWeb, but that effort seems to be fairly dead at the moment.